# Why it does not work in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create simple database engine. I have a problem with structures.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    struct LICZBY
    {
        int wartosc;
    };

    struct STUDENCI
    {
        int indeks;
        string imie;
        string nazwisko;
    };

    struct PRZEDMIOTY
    {
        int id;
        string nazwa;   // auto
        int semestr;    // clamp (1/10)
    };

    struct SALE
    {
        string nazwa;
        int rozmiar;    // clamp (10/600)
        bool projektor;
        double powierzchnia;
    };

    struct TABLES
    {
        vector<LICZBY> liczby;
        vector<STUDENCI> studenci;
        vector<PRZEDMIOTY> przedmioty;
        vector<SALE> sale;
    };

int main() {
    TABLES tables;
    tables.liczby.push_back({1});

    cout << tables.liczby[0].wartosc;

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012. This code return an error: expected an expression (here **tables.liczby.push_back({1});**), but code works at ideone.com.
http://ideone.com/fork/zc9pz8

What is wrong? Please give me some advise.

Comment: Not yet supported in VS2012, available in VS2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2012 does not yet support C++11 uniform initialization syntax/semantics, which is what's required for your `{1}` to work in this context.

- At this time it cannot be rewritten as a one-liner for VS2012 (unless you declare a conversion constructor in your `LICZBY` class). For the original definition of `LICZBY` you can only rewrite it as

  ```
  const LICZBY liczby = { 1 };
  tables.liczby.push_back(liczby);
  ```
- If you add a conversion constructor

  ```
  struct LICZBY
  {
      int wartosc;
      LICZBY(int wartosc) : wartosc(wartosc) {}
  };
  ```

  then you'll be able to do it as

  ```
  tables.liczby.push_back(1);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
tables.liczby.push_back({1});
```

is trying to use an initializer list. This is supported by the gcc version used on ideone, but is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) by VS2012. In this case, it's an easy fix:

```
tables.liczby.push_back(LICZBY(1));
```

Comment: Easy fix? This will not compile. Class `LICZBY` has no constructor. Expression `LICZBY(1)` is invalid.